# How to animate Reach Router Redirect with react-transition-group

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, reactcsstransitiongroup, reach-router

My App component looks like this:

```
<TransitionGroup className={s.group}>
    <CSSTransition key={location.key} timeout={150} classNames={classNames}>
        <Router location={location} className={s.content}>
            <MainScreen path={routes.main} />
            <IntroductionScreen path={routes.introduction} />
            <ProfileScreen path={routes.profile} />
            <AuthScreen path={routes.auth} />
        </Router>
    </CSSTransition>
</TransitionGroup>
```

It works well, but when I return Redirect component from ProfileScreen component, the animation doesn't work and I get the following error:

[image: Error]

My ProfileScreen component:

```
const ProfileScreen: FunctionComponent<RouteComponentProps> = (props) => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search.substring(1));
    const token = urlParams.get('token');

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!token) {
            redirectTo(routes.auth);
        }
    }, [token]);

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Hello!</h1>
        </>
    );
};
```

What is the reason for the exception? How can I make the animation work?

Comment: What is the `redirectTo` function? I can't find it in react-router package

Comment: @AlexChashin I use @reach/router. [redicrectTo method](https://reach.tech/router/api/redirectTo)

Comment: It seems like `redirecTo` is implemented using exception that is caught by `Router` that does the actual redirect. If you see this exception in console, it means that somehow `ProfileScreen` was rendered whereas `Router` was not. It's hard to tell exactly why this is, probably has to do with both `@reach/router` and `react-transition-group` tinkering with react's internal rendering mechanisms. In `react-router` you usually put `Router` outside of transition, so that it's always rendered, and only put actual routes inside transition. Not sure if you can do it with `@reach/router` though

Comment: Maybe you could try something like `<Router><TransitionGroup path="/" ...><CSSTransition path="/" ...><ProfileMenu path="..." /></CSSTransition></TransitionGroup></Router>` so that `Router` is in the root of the components tree but it still sees `ProfileMenu` as a route component, I'm not sure, never used this library